# Shorten a Python Django DB query

Tags: python, django, database

We have m2m relationship between `E` and `U` models:

```
class E(models.Model):
    us = models.ManyToManyField('U', related_name='events', symmetrical=False)

class U(models.Model):
    pass
```

Now we want to remove all links for U with pk=2.

I wrote this code: `U.events.through.objects.filter(u=2).delete()`.

Can this code be shortened/simplified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
U.objects.get(pk=2).events.clear()
```

There are some useful examples in the Django documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

As a side note, you don't need `symmetrical=False` on your many to many definition. Quoting from the Django documentation:

> Only used in the definition of ManyToManyFields on self.

See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

Comment: sidenote: clear and delete aren't the same. @porton wanted to remove _links_ from one object of the other and was trying `delete`. clear is correct, delete probably not https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear , https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.delete